# the width of the composite is getting changed when we press on the maximise button in eclipse plugin development using swt

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt

The width of the `Composite` is getting changed when we press on maximize button in the titlebar of the wizard in eclipse plugin development, using SWT.

How can I overcome this problem?

**Note**: I am not using **KFace**, `WizardDialog`, `Shell`, `Display`. I am using only `Composite` and my main class is implementing `IWizard`.

```
public void createControl(Composite parent) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
    composite.setLayout(new GridLayout());  

    /*GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout();
    gridLayout.verticalSpacing = 10;
    //gridLayout.makeColumnsEqualWidth = true;
    //gridLayout.numColumns = 2;*/  

    Composite operationsListComposite = new Composite(composite, SWT.NONE);
    operationsListComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,false));
    operationsListComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(
            GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL));     

    Label operationLabel = new Label(operationsListComposite, SWT.NONE);
    operationLabel.setText("");

    //Label emptyLabel = new Label(operationsListComposite, SWT.NONE);
    //emptyLabel.setText("");

    Label adapterLabel = new Label(operationsListComposite, SWT.NONE);
    adapterLabel.setText("");       

    fileGroupsList = new List(operationsListComposite,SWT.BORDER
            | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
    fileGroupsList.add("JSP1");
    fileGroupsList.add("JSP2");
    fileGroupsList.add("JSP3");
    fileGroupsList.add("JSP4");
    fileGroupsList.addListener(SWT.Selection, this);

    //operationsTree = new Tree(operationsListComposite,SWT.BORDER
    //      | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
    //operationsTree.addListener(SWT.Selection, this);
    GridData data = new GridData();
    data.horizontalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
    data.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
    data.heightHint = 150;
    data.widthHint=100;
    //operationsTree.setLayoutData(data);
    fileGroupsList.setLayoutData(data);


    //filesList = new List(operationsListComposite,SWT.BORDER
    //      | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
    Composite css1Composite = new Composite(operationsListComposite, SWT.BORDER);
    GridData gridData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false);
    //gridData.horizontalSpan= 2;
    gridData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
    css1Composite.setLayoutData(gridData);
    GridLayout grpL = new GridLayout(3,false);
    grpL.verticalSpacing=0;
    css1Composite.setLayout(grpL);
    }}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code where you create the composite. Normally you want the composite to resize when the dialog size changes.

Comment: yes, i create my composite in createControl method

Comment: The use `GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL` is not recommended. See [this](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/layout/GridData.html#FILL_HORIZONTAL).

Answer (score 2):

```
operationsListComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(
            GridData.FILL_HORIZONTAL));
```

tells SWT that you want the composite to fill all the space which is why is expands on the resize.

```
GridData data = new GridData(SWT.BEGINNING, SWT.TOP, false, false);
data.widthHint = 100;
operationsList.setLayoutData(data);
```

Stops the composite for resizing and gives a suggested size - 100.

Edit:
You may not need the width hint.

Comment: If there are two subcomposites under parent composite and they should be aligned horizontally,  what should i give in gridData for horizontal alignment?

Comment: If you want two composites one above the other you will get that with the above layout.

Comment: Using "widthHint" is evil. The whole layout will be ruined when the user decides to change the system font.